# Why is 'document' is not defined error on webpack build?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am preparing to put a small react app on Heroku and am working on a production  config. When I run `npm run build` all works. However, when I got to run the built file `node dist/dist.js` I receive the error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Should I be using a different css loader? 
My webpack.deployment.config.js is as follows:

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: [
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: './dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    },
     { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" },
     { test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/, use: 'file-loader'}

    ]
  },
};
```

Comment: Something in your javascript code is trying to access the global variable `document`, which is only available on browsers. The solution is to not execute that code in nodejs, but it's difficult to help without seeing that code.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Prior to this I was having a window is undefined issued when using { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }.   I guess it makes more sense to finish the build and deploy it so it has a browser. Thank you.

Comment: Webpack is useful but garbagey and confusing. In local development, you can use the `style-loader`, which actually turns your css into javascript that's executed which dynamically injects a css tag in the page and puts the string css contents in there (this lets you hot reload for example). On a production build (which you should make a new webpack config file for) - you use the ExtractTextPlugin and *not* the style-loader, just the css-loader, to pull out the css into actual separate files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm module `jsdom` can be used to make window and document available in non-browser environments.